# Large memory blocks in a .NET app. What's optimal/recommended/scalable way to handle them?

Tags: c#, optimization, memory-management, large-files

Imagine an application that creates large files by combining and/or editing other files.
For example, an application that:

- opens an archive of images
- adds or replaces some of the images
- changes parts of existing images
- creates new archive with resulting set of images

Images can be added/replaced/changed in any order, so the new archive can't be created until the very end of execution.

Naive approach would be to create a set of `MemoryStream` objects for each image in the original archive, then change/remove/replace streams when needed and then write the set to a new archive. Such approach will probably give best result in terms of execution speed.

The problem is obvious: there is not always enough memory to hold the set of streams.

*What would you recommend in this case?*

I guess I should trade some speed for memory and use some kind of temporary off-memory storage. I am not sure what to use, though.

*Should I use memory-mapped files? Or plain old temporary files with some mechanism for creation and deletion of them? Maybe something else?*

Comment: Do you have any performance requirements?  I'd be tempted to go for plain temporary files (probably stored in a nested structure to avoid the slow down of many small files) and start there.  If you hide behind an appropriate interface, you can always change your mind later!

Comment: Have you considered using Microsoft's Esent ? Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine ESENT Managed .Net lib: https://managedesent.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JeffFoster I would like to retain as much speed as possible, of course. Other than that I have no special performance requirements.

Comment: @YS. I never heard of that before. Thank you, I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use files and file system - for the most part of it - and provide some sort of memory caching or mapping.

If you're dealing with large amount of or sizable files - then you can't really match that with the memory size (or unpack the full archive in memory) - unless we're talking extra h/w, RAM.

Specifically, I'd personally go with something like...

```
class MemoryArchive {}
```

...which is posing as a front for you files, archive in the back-end.

You unpack the archive on the disk, temp files folder - similarly as most unzip utils do, and then deal with 'smaller units' of access, i.e. files.

Your `MemoryArchive` is basically behaving like all is in memory, so you'd need to have some mapping in place of memory streams (or whatever you decide to use for direct access on object level) into temporary files on the disk, file streams.

And probably some robust way of handling the synchronization - and/or errors, problems - as you need to make sure that what's in memory gets synchronized with the content on the disk - and keep the 'integration' intact.

At that point (and depending on the nature of your system etc.) the major task may be having to code some sort of transactions - around the file system storage - which is where you begin to resemble a database management system. But that'd be on the other 'end of the scale' - and if you can live without it, and keep it simple, it might not be that problematic.

Just an idea, though it'd all depend on your specific details -
i.e. the scale of things (that could vary a lot - i.e. if memory allows in certain cases you could load, and if processing is fast enough), how 'small changes' within the archive vs how large archives are, frequency and nature of changes.

In the easiest case, I'd pretty much go with storing things as temporary files and dealing with smaller incremental changes as needed.

And having some sort of `MemoryArchive` would give you a fence around things for the future - so you could change that, or mix couple approaches based on the e.g. size of archives etc. Actually some 'mix of approaches' is what's usually best in these scenarios, as you can hardly make a 'one fits all' solution when dealing with different files, sizes.

hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FileStream` and use it the same way as you would a `MemoryStream`. It essentially puts the burden of determining buffering and all of that on the OS. The OS does know best and lets drivers and hardware take care of the intricacies of caching and fine tuning. Just write the code that is easy to understand and profile, profile, profile.

You can probably mix the two types of streams to get something that performs well and looks nice, if profiling shows a need.

Comment: This is essentially plain old temporary files, right? I will try them too.

Comment: @Bobrovsky Yep, pretty much. A hybrid based on your profiling results would probably serve you best and give you a specifically tuned result.

Answer (score 2):

First, please be aware of [.net limitation with LOH](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521147/large-object-heap-fragmentation-causes-outofmemoryexception), basically with LOH objects the memory does not defragment, so if you are creating and disposing a lot of big objects in succession you'd  "most probably" get "out of memory exception" as fragmented memory holes may not give you a big enough consecutive memory space (.net 4.5 and above has optimized this to certain extent but the problem still persists). So to answer your question, a lot depends on the architecture of your box, if it is a 64 bit with plenty of RAM and you know your files will fit in just right with the LOH issue, do use in-memory objects, otherwise as Michael suggested go with the filestream thrashing is bound to happen.

Comment: Thank you for the warning about LOH limitation. I guess I've already seen consequences of this limitation but didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use memory-mapped files?

That would certainly be the first thing that comes to mind. The only issue with this approach is if the file size end up consuming all the mapped space.

Comment: I need to process many files. Maybe even thousands of them. Thank you for the warning, I will ask google about for mapped space constraints.